# SQL - Two rows with only one differet column value. How to keep one and filter the other?

Tags: sql, ssms

Im working on a project where there are two rows with the exact same values except one column. How am I supposed to filter out one of the rows only when two entries exist?

Example 1 Chart:

```
R_Num        R_Name       Results 
1001         NAME_1       PASSED 
1002         NAME_2       PASSED 
1002         NAME_2       FAILED 
1003         NAME_3       FAILED 
1004         NAME_4       PASSED 
1004         NAME 4       FAILED
```

1005

Resulting Chart:

```
R_Num        R_Name       Results
1001         NAME_1       PASSED 
1002         NAME_2       PASSED 
1003         NAME_3       FAILED 
1004         NAME_4       PASSED
```

I want to be able to get rid of the rows where there is both pass and fail for a given R, and only keep the pass row.

```
EXAMPLE 2:

 R_Num       R_Name        Results  
   1         Apple         PASSED  
   2         Banana        FAILED 
   3         Coconut       PASSED 
   3         Coconut       FAILED  
   4         Dates         PASSED 
   5         Elderberry    FAILED  
   6         Fig           PASSED  
   6         Fig           FAILED  

RESULTS AFTER QUERY:  

 R_Num       R_Name        Results  
   1         Apple         PASSED  
   2         Banana        FAILED  
   3         Coconut       PASSED   
   4         Dates         PASSED  
   5         Elderberry    FAILED  
   6         Fig           PASSED
```

I need to keep the FAILED values where there is no identical R that has passed.

Comment: Which one you wants to keep? Passed or Failed? Or any one?

Comment: I've tried using max and group by, but the issue is I want to keep failed if there is no row with the same R_num and R_name that says passed. The max function only returns all the passes.

Comment: Add some more variety in your sample data to make the requirement clear.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `max()`

```
 select R_Num, R_Name, max(Results) as Results
   from tab
  group by R_Num, R_Name
```

Comment: You probably want `GROUP BY R_Num, R_Name`

Comment: I tried this previously but it did not work. I added more examples and information for exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select r_num, r_name, max(results)
from t
group by r_num, r_name;
```

`'pass'` > `'fail'` alphabetically, so it will be returned if both are present.